# Error when restoring up a database backup: Cannot find file ID 1 on device

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

Below is the query that I am using to restore my database.

However, whenever I run it, i always get this error message:

> Msg 4038, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find file ID 1 on device 'D:\DB_Backup\MMS.BAK'.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

This is my query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE METERIAL_MANAGEMENT_2 
FROM DISK = 'D:\DB_Backup\MMS.BAK'
WITH 
    MOVE 'METERIAL_MANAGEMENT' TO 'D:\DATA\METERIAL_MANAGEMENT_2.mdf',
    MOVE 'METERIAL_MANAGEMENT_log' TO 'D:\DATA\METERIAL_MANAGEMENT_2_Log.ldf'
```

Comment: Your code uses `RESTORE DATABASE`, which is used to restore a database from a file, not back up a database to a file.  Use [`BACKUP DATABASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) to create the backup file.

Comment: Run `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\DB_BACKUP\MMS.BAK';` to see what backups are listed in the file.  Perhaps the file doesn't contain any valid database backups, or is corrupted in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is for Restoring a database not to create a backup file. you have to use the following code:

```
BACKUP DATABASE METERIAL_MANAGEMENT_2 
TO DISK = 'D:\DB_Backup\MMS.BAK'
```

Read more about Creating a full backup using T-SQL in the following [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx)